# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(x-3)^n$ converges for $x=0$, and diverges for $x=7$. Does $\sum C_n$ converge? $\sum C_n5^n$? $\sum C_n\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$?

Tags: power-series

> Suppose a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(x-3)^n$ converges when $x=0$ and diverges when $x=7$. Determine which series below will definitely converge.
>
> I) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n$
>
> II) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n5^n$
>
> III) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}$
>
> IV) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n3^n$

Comment: *Hint:* you know that $\sum C_n 4^n = \infty$ and $\sum C_n (-1)^n 3^n < \infty$. For example, this implies that (II) always diverges and you cannot conclude anything about (IV)

Comment: The information that you have tells you that the series converges (absolutely) in an open interval with center $3$ and radius $|0-3|=3$. This is, the interval $(0,6)$. It also converges at $0$. They also tell you that it diverges in the exterior of the interval with center $3$ and radius $|7-3|=4$. This is, in the complement of $[-1,7]$. Now check for each of those series what value you would need to replace the $x$ for, to get the given series, and check if it falls into one of these sets.

Comment: Note that the convergence of all the series can be determined from the information given, except for (IV). You will need to give examples of both cases to prove that one cannot tell from the information given.

Comment: Try the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-3)^3}{3^nn}$ and the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-3)^n}{(7/2)^n}$ to show that (IV) cannot be definitely decided.

Comment: @conditionalMethod why would I need examples of both cases when we just know that it is equally possible $x=6$ is convergent or divergent?

Comment: You just know? How? The only reason why we know is that we have examples of both behaviors. Note that an argument like "All the results that I know don't imply convergence or divergence" doesn't disprove that convergence isn't certain.

Comment: @conditionalMethod We know $[0, 6)$ is the smallest possible interval of convergence and $[-1, 7)$ is the largest possible interval of convergence. Therefore, $[0, 6]$ and $[0, 6)$ are both possible.

Comment: That is not a proof. That is only the conclusion that you want to obtain, without explanation of why it is true. To prove that both cases are possible, you give examples of both.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I don't get how $[0,6)$ isn't a possible interval. It includes zero and $7$ is out of this range so $7$ is divergent.

Comment: $[0,6)$ is a possible interval, and so is $[-1,7)$. But how do you prove that claim? By giving examples of both. note that what follows immediately from the information given is that $[0,6)$ will be contained and that all points of $[-1,7)^c$ wont be contained. The first claim and this are two different non-equivalent in general claims. In particular, to answer (IV) one needs to show that $[0,6)$ is a possible interval of convergence of one of those types of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that power series is centered at $3$, diverges at $7$ and converges at $0$, the radius of convergence is between $3$ and $4$. So, the series that will definitely converge are the series I) and III).

Comment: How do I rewrite I) and III) in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(x-3)^n$?

Comment: In the case of I), simply take $x=4$. In the case of III), you know that your power series converges in an open interval to which $5$ belongs. So, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ also convergs on that interval.Now, take $x=5$.

Comment: Can you help me understand why my logic of "We know $[0,6)$ is the smallest possible interval of convergence and $[−1,7)$ is the largest possible interval of convergence" is false. conditionalMethod is helping me and I would appreciate your help as well

Comment: No, I cannot help you, since I agree with you.

Comment: Then what is conditionalMethod saying?

Comment: Does my answer provide an answer to your question or not?

Comment: It does, I was just going to clarify how you know $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is definitely convergent on $[0, 6)$ but conditionalMethod confused me.

Comment: Your answer is clearly incomplete. Not only for the missing arguments that can be easily filled up, but for missing the crucial and substantially distinct argument needed to answer (IV).

Comment: @conditionalMethod Because I did not justify why II) and IV) are not necessarily convergent?

Comment: (II) falls into melange of just bounding radii of convergence. However, (IV) requires examples. Not difficult examples, but user532874 doesn't seem to see why they are needed.

Comment: It is easy to find an example in which IV) diverges. Just take $C_n=\frac1{n3^n}$.

Comment: The power series is centered at $3$. If it diverges when $x=7$, then it also diverges when $x=8$. So, the series II) diverges.

Comment: Deducing the answer of (II) doesn't require examples. It follows from comparing with the series diverging at $x=7$. (IV) is the one that does require them.

Comment: Compare that assertion with my previous comment.

Comment: Why would IV require examples? We know any $x$ value less than $6$ and greater than or equal to zero is guaranteed to be convergent. $x=6$ is not one of these values so it could be convergent or divergent. Isn't this just common sense?

Comment: And how do you know $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is convergent for sure on $[0,6)$?

Comment: No, it is **not** just common sense. If you assert that if *may* diverge when $x=6$, the natural way of doing that consists in providing an example. And I never claimed that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ converges on $[0,6)$, only on $(0,6)$. There is a theorem about power series that says that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$ converges on $(a-r,a+r)$, then so does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.